# Images not showing up from View files of yeoman built angular app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have built an application using Yeoman and AngularJS (using generator-angular).

Everything works fine when running locally using grunt serve. However, after running grunt build and deploying the application, the images that are in the views have an incorrect url.

My directory structure looks like this (just the part needed to explain this question):

```
/app
    /images
        eiffeltower.png
    /views
        my-view.html
    index.html
/dist
    /images
        eiffeltower.png
    /views
        my-view.html
    index.html
```

In the view **my-view.html** i have some code like this:

```
<img src="../images/eiffeltower.png">
```

After I build the app with **grunt build** I go to the app with the url:

```
localhost/angularapp/dist/#/my-view
```

There the html of the image looks like `<img scr="../images/eiffeltower.png">`, however the image is coming up 404.  If I use google inspector and edit the img scr to this `<img scr="images/eiffeltower.png">` then it shows up.

I have not modified any of the Gruntfile.js. How can I get the images in the angular views to be processed correctly by grunt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An angular app is a single page application. For the browser everything is relative to index.html, so make the url's to other resources also relative to index.html
If you refer to your images in the src like src="images/eiffeltower.png" it should work fine from grunt serve and from the dist.